# logo email doesn't show on mailbox of the customer

Tags: module, overrides, email-templates, logo

in my case i am using magento 2.2.x , so i want to override the file **"vendor/magento/module-email/view/frontend/email/header.html"** in order to add a logo in the email to show the company's logo in the customer's mailbox side , but it doesn't work, i can't see the icon for the alt attribute that means the picture is there but still not showing in the header of the mail

i call the image from a custom module **Mymodule_Email** sequence of **Magento_Email**

my file inside app/design dir  to override : vendor/magento/module-email/view/frontend/email/header.htm:

```
<table class="wrapper" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapper-inner" align="center">
            <table class="main" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="header">
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Mymodule_Email::images/logo.png'); ?>"
                        />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="main-content">
                        <!-- Begin Content -->
```

PS : when i use simple syntax it works , for example **`<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" />`**
PS : file structure and path for the image  is good : 'Mymodule_Email::images/logo.png'

> can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Hey, try to inspect the email image and see if the path that magento it's generating for the image it's correct might give a hint

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't add PHP code in html file.

You can add or change email logo from admin.

Please prefer this link [Magento DevDocs for Email Templates](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html)

Steps to upload logo from admin is :: Magento Admin > CONTENT > Design > Configuration > Select your store scope > [image] > Save Configuration

If this helps you then hit like.

Thank you

Hiren Patel

Comment: Thank you for your response , but i want to do it by code in order to keep changes to different instances , do you have any suggestion?